# PHP - mySQL query issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, latitude-longitude

I'm finding the nearest location (with long/lat from Google API) in a radius area with lon/lat in my SQL database, here's my query:

```
$query = "SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(".$lat.") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(".$long.") ) + sin( radians(".$lat.") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM finder_location HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1";

    $result = mysql_query( $query );

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['id'];
```

The query is returning correctly inside phpMyAdmin as:

```
id  9
distance 0.74066713768542
```

So, the query is compiling correctly...

But, when I tried to output in PHP, I get these errors:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '>) ) * cos(
>   radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon )
>   - radians(-73.988307 ) )' at line 1 Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource

Comment: You need to look at the final, generated query in PHP (`echo $query;`). Some of your variables seem to be empty.

Comment: possibly $lat variable contains invalid value, check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your php `$lat` variable is not populated correctly. You can see the trailing end of an html tag in the mysql error. Debug your `$lat` and `$long` to make sure they have the correct values before the query.

Comment: those variables are outputting straight long and lat:  40.66677,
-73.988307

Comment: maybe it is outputting `<span>40.66677</span>` that looks like `40.66677` in your browser, but actually has some html wrapped around the value.

Comment: Nope, just line breaks from the two echos:
40.66677<br />-73.988307<br />

Comment: echo does not produce html line breaks. I think they are creeping in to your variable somehow. Try `echo "::$lat::";` and the result should be `::40.66677::` without any line breaks or anything in-between.

Comment: Weird coding script was adding line breaks, it works now, thank you SO much!